# downvote/downvoted reputation rename

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, reputation-history

In the beginning I found it confusing as a new user that you received negative rep for downvoting someone's answer. In the reputation overview, the description said "downvoted", which is only one letter different from "downvote". I therefore suggested that the events should be renamed to "received downvote" and/or "gave downvote" or something else that is clear and appropriate, so as not to confuse any other newcomers.

Comment: +1 I agree, the words seem to be inversed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can already hover over that text for a more detailed description:

- `downvoted` :: `downvoted a post`
- `downvote` :: `post was downvoted`

Additionally, when you *issue* a downvote, you only lose 1 reputation, whereas when you *receive* a downvote, you lose 2 reputation. Just going by the number at the left, you should be able to figure it out.

If all these indicators still aren't clear enough for you, you'll need a bit more evidence to convince them that this is a real issue, rather than just you being slightly confused.

Comment: I didn't know about the hover text.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Fun fact, these hover texts are all over the place here.

Comment: How do people *miss* the hover text? Does everyone have a touch screen now or what?

Comment: Yup, the hover text serves this purpose while leaving maximum room in the UI.

Comment: I like the hover text now that I know where it is (everywhere), but  I think it's very non-obvious. Few sites do it this much (or I'm universally oblivious) and those that do usually have some visual hint. @TheEstablishment Touch screen? I use the keyboard.