# Shouldn't be description about downvoting reversed on rep history?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, down-votes

When you see your reputation history there is two words for downvotes, "**downvote**" and "**downvoted**", representing when your post was downvoted and when you make a downvote.

It feels like it should be the wrong way:
[image]

I think it should be "**downvoted**" when you were downvoted and "**downvote**" for the downvotes you made. Or maybe changed all together to different words.

Maybe is this a bug? Maybe my understanding of English is not good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once asked to rename these similar descriptions: [downvote/downvoted reputation rename](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130969/downvote-downvoted-reputation-rename)

Seems that I'm not the only one it confused, but anyway they won't change it apparently.

Comment: I find it confusing, good to know I'm not the only one

Comment: @SysDragon Must be there aren't many users that are confused by it or maybe none of them really care. Anyway it's a one-off situation. The answer in the question I linked to is pretty helpful.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not a bug, this is by design.

"downvote" means that you receive a downvote.
"downvoted" means that you gave a downvote to an answer.

Comment: Feels like it should be the other way around, it's just me?

Comment: @SysDragon Personally, I find it clear as it stands now. It seems like the opinions are split about it, because the renaming feature-request has 4 upvotes and 4 downvotes.

Comment: @SysDragon Either way seems strictly correct to me, but you need the hover text or the knowledge of the fact that your own down-vote is -1 rather than -2 to know which is which. Expecialy for non-native English speakers like you and me this probably seems odd.